# Change a specific page background?

Tags: css, wordpress

On this page : https://nutreviva.com/peak-health-essentials/ I am trying to fully change the background of the page from white to ivory.

When I try to do this it is only changes to the top half middle sections between the boxes and at the bottom of the page.  The sides of the page are still white and this is driving me up the wall.

I have scoured the Inspect in Chrome but nothing seems to be working. When i do, it changes the background for the rest of the pages too zzz

Comment: You are required to post your markup and code here, not your web site which will change or disappear and make your question useless to anyone in the future. [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `custom.css` file I'd add the following:

```
body.page-id-3811 {
    background-color: ivory;
}
```

It seems to work fine, I'm only able to see the colour white background colour in the header and the panels.

Comment: This will apply to all pages, not just this 1 that he needs

Comment: This nailed it!

I tried so many ways, but i think i had certain elements back to front.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular pages HTML try making it say this:
`<body style="background-color: ivory;"` and see if that is what you are after

Comment: Would also like to add that ivory as a background colour looks nice here, good choice!

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions that do not supply the required markup here. Not all questions should be answered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Obviously you didn't read my link. Have you ever read the Help section?

Comment: None of the 5 points listed under what questions shouldn't be answered fit this current situation, so not sure what you are getting at but you're welcome to stop attacking me for helping someone who is clearly struggling with css...

Comment: Hi thanks for assisting, so would i need to add the .page-3811 .body style="background-color: ivory;"

Comment: Obviously you have not read the Help section. His question will soon be closed and you will have wasted everyone's time. The only markup supplied is his web site. When that is fixed, it renders the question and your answer unusable. That is why such questions should not be answered at all.

Comment: @PeleRoberts no this would go in the HTML of the page

Comment: ah ok, is there not a way to do this using CSS to that particular page only ?

@Rob what do you mean by markup? Im unsure.

Comment: I would need to see more of the source code to tell you if you could do it straight through css.

Comment: @PeleRoberts HTML is a "markup language". CSS is your styling language. They should not be referred to as "code" which typically means a programming language. You need to supply that in your question, not your web site: [mcve]

Comment: Ah ok gotcha!, WIll keep that in mind in future. Thanks